# Replace node in XML using groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy

I need help in replace XML node using Groovy script. Each `<document_owner__c><value>9231799</value></document_owner__c>` should be replaced with `<Manager>1234</Manager>`. Given below sample input and required output.

Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <root>
   <row>
        <id>728</id>
        <document_owner__c>
            <value>9231799</value>
        </document_owner__c>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>713</id>
        <document_owner__c>
            <value>9231799</value>
        </document_owner__c>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>707</id>
        <document_owner__c>
            <value>9231799</value>
        </document_owner__c>
    </row>
    </root>
```

Required Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <root>
   <row>
        <id>728</id>
        <Manager>1234<Manager>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>713</id>
        <Manager>1234<Manager>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>707</id>
        <Manager>1234<Manager>
    </row>
    </root>
```

Comment: You need a groovy script or vanilla XSLT? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why does it need to be done with Groovy instead of DataWeave, which is built in in Mule?

Comment: Also the description is incorrect. Based on the example you want to replace element `document_owner__c` with `<Manager>1234<Manager>`.

Comment: hi I need groovy script for this requirement

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using DataWeave. I wrote a parametrized function that recursively transforms the desired key and replaces it with a new element, which is an Object in DataWeave types.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
fun replaceElement(originalObject, key, newObject)=
    originalObject  match {
            case is Object -> originalObject mapObject (if($$ as String == key) newObject else ($$): replaceElement($, key, newObject))
            else -> $
    }
---
replaceElement(payload, "document_owner__c", {Manager: "1234"})
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a working jenkins job that does something similar. I have extracted some code from it and modified for your scenario. Heres the Groovy script:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def oldXml = """
<root>
   <row>
        <id>728</id>
        <document_owner__c>
            <value>9231799</value>
        </document_owner__c>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>713</id>
        <document_owner__c>
            <value>9231799</value>
        </document_owner__c>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>707</id>
        <document_owner__c>
            <value>9231799</value>
        </document_owner__c>
    </row>
</root>
"""

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(oldXml)
root.row
    .findAll {it.document_owner__c.value.text().equals('9231799') }
    .document_owner__c
    .replaceNode { Manager("1234") }

def newXml = XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {mkp.yield root})

println newXml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <row>
    <id>728</id>
    <Manager>1234</Manager>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>713</id>
    <Manager>1234</Manager>
  </row>
  <row>
    <id>707</id>
    <Manager>1234</Manager>
  </row>
</root>
```